# Mathematica9 linux version crash, how to fix it?

Tags: linux

Ubuntu 12.04  x86_64   kernel 3.2.0-35-generic
*Mathematica* 9 linux version (x86_64) crashes with errors:

> X Error of failed request:  BadGC (invalid GC parameter)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  59 (X_SetClipRectangles)
>   Resource id in failed request:  0x0
>   Serial number of failed request:  2266
>   Current serial number in output stream:  2268
>
> X Error of failed request:  BadGC (invalid GC parameter)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  59 (X_SetClipRectangles)
>   Resource id in failed request:  0x0
>   Serial number of failed request:  2267
>   Current serial number in output stream:  2268
>
> ...

The above errors occur when I run command `mathematica` as a general user. It crashes before GUI is started. However, if I run it as root `sudo mathematica`, all work well.

Can someone fix this problem?

Comment: How good are you with the command-line? [This answer](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-944866.html) suggests, that it is a problem with the wrong Qt-libraries. You could use `ldd` to find out which libraries are used but it's a bit of work.

Comment: Antoher thing: Which desktop-environment are you using? I use the classic gnome (otherwise I have the same system as you) and everything works fine. Have you tried to select a different one? You can do this at the login-screen.

Comment: I use KDE desktop.

Comment: And can you debug what Qt libraries are use? If not, you can [come to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica) and I help you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thank  halirutan very much! It's really the problem of a setting for QT. Mathematica9 crashes when "systemsettings -> Qt Graphics System -> Raster" is selected. This changes the file `~/.kde/env/qt-graphicssystem.sh` and hence the `QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM` envirenment variable.

```
QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native  mathematica   # work
QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=raster  mathematica   # crash
QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=opengl  mathematica   # work
```

Answer (score 4):

Since this question was the only page I found on the Web that actually led to the solution of my problems with Mathematica 9.0 installation, let me summarize the steps I had to take to make it working on my x86_64 kubuntu desktop:

1. I had to **remove** from /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64 the **libQt*.so.4** files (indeed I made backups). This solved the error "Qt issued a fatal error: Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40704) with this library (version 0x40703)", but mathematica still crashed with other error.
2. Then I put the prefix QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native into the mathematica startup script and mathematica 9.0 now works.

Thanks to Mr. goodluck!